# Search for files in a folder

Tags: julia

I'm trying parse a lot of text files using Julia, and I want to loop across an array of file names instead of typing out a function call to read each of them individually. So far I have been unable to find a way to search a folder for files matching a pattern.

Is there a base library Julia function that will return all file names in a given folder, matching a given string pattern?

The equivalent function in R would be `list.files()`, if that helps communicate what I want.

Comment: MDe, you might consider updating your answer. The Glob.jl package in @Trock's answer is much more direct and readable than the oneliner hack.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use the [Glob.jl](https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl) package. For example, if you have the following list of files in your directory:

```
foo1.txt
foo2.txt
foo3.txt
bar1.txt
foo.jl
```

and you want to find all text files starting with "foo" you would write

```
using Glob
glob("foo*.txt") #if searching the working directory
#output:
#"foo1.txt"
#"foo2.txt"
#"foo3.txt"
glob("foo*.txt","path/to/dir") #for specifying a different directory
#output:
#"path/to/dir/foo1.txt"
#"path/to/dir/foo2.txt"
#"path/to/dir/foo3.txt"
```

Answer (score 54):

In Julia, the equivalent to `list.files()` is `readdir([path])`

There is no built-in directory search that I know of, but it is a one-liner:

`searchdir(path,key) = filter(x->contains(x,key), readdir(path))`

---

**UPDATE**: Since at least Julia v0.7, `contains()` has been deprecated for `occursin(substring, string)`. So the above filter would now be:

```
searchdir(path,key) = filter(x->occursin(key,x), readdir(path))
```

Comment: As a supplement: similar to `contains` the following functions might be useful: `isfile`, `isdir`, `startswith`, `endswith`.

Comment: you can also use `readdir(expanduser(path))` to convert `~` to home dir (under linux). Also regular expression can be used: `searchdir("~/Package/MyPackage/src/",r".jl$")`

Comment: contains is available again after Julia 1.5